# Dojo BorderContainer Layout

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout, border-container

Currently I have a borderContainer layout as shown below:

[image]

My code for this layout is:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'sidebar', gutters:true, liveSplitters:true" id="borderContainer">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'left'" style="width: 150px;" id="treeSection">Tree menu display here</div>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'top'" style="height:200px;" id="gridSection">Dojo Grid display here
</div>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'center'" id="contactView" data-dojo-id="contactView">contact detail here
</div>
</div>
```

I want to have a layout as (2 column, right column has 3 rows) shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another widget to the top region.

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter:true, 
  region:'top'" style="height:20px;" id="pageSection">
  Pagination goes here
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/Kjr78/

See also:

[Dojo: Can I add two or more widgets to the same BorderContainer region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042631/dojo-can-i-add-two-or-more-widgets-to-the-same-bordercontainer-region/11042955#11042955)

Answer (score 1):

BorderContainers can be embedded as regions. Your example would be:

- bordercontainer (parent)

  - contentpane (region left explicit width)
  - contentpane (region top explicit height)
  - bordercontainer (region center, fluid)

    - contentpane (region top, explicit height)
    - contentpane (region center, fluid)

Comment: I have tried this approach before and found it difficult to maintain a consistent padding between all the widgets.